# Yocto & Rust - recipe fails to generate correct build dependencies

Tags: rust, yocto, bitbake, openembedded, yocto-recipe

I am trying to build a **Rust** application for **Yocto** which uses a number of **bindgen** generated bindings to custom `ioctl` calls. My recipe includes the following dependency line:

```
DEPENDS += " clang ncurses ncurses-native libsdl2"
export LIBCLANG_PATH = "${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/${libdir}"
```

When I try to build the recipe with `bitbake` I get the following error:

```
|   thread 'main' panicked at 'Unable to find libclang: "the `libclang` 
    shared library at 
${WORKDIR}/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/dummy-reader-sdl2/
          0.1.0.AUTOINC+d2766c10a0-r0/recipe-sysroot/
          usr/lib/libclang.so.14.0.3 could not be opened: 
          libncurses.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"', 

${WORKDIR}/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/dummy-reader-sdl2/
          0.1.0.AUTOINC+d2766c10a0-r0/
          cargo_home/bitbake/bindgen-0.59.2/src/lib.rs:2144:31
```

When I look in the `recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/` I can see that it is populated with `lib clang.so` but `libncurses.so.5` is missing (there  is a `libncurses.so` library).

Further searching revealed that the missing `libncurses.so.5` is present in `recipe-sysroot/lib/`. If I manually add a link (i.e. `ln -s ../../lib/libncurses.so.5 libncurses.so.5` I can re-run **bitbake** and by application builds correctly and runs on the target hardware. This is obviously a hack and I need to find a proper solution.

Note. `recipe-sysroot/lib/` does not contain `libclang.so`

**How do I configure my recipe so that either:**

`libclang.so`

1. `libncurses.so.5` & `libclang.so` are populated to the same directory (either `recipe-sysroot/lib/`or `recipe-sysroot/usr/lib/`)
2. The dependencies for `libclang.so` search in `recipe-sysroot/lib/`

Comment: If anyone knows a better place to ask for Yocto support please add a comment

Comment: Maybe with `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = "${RECIPE_SYSROOT}/lib:${RECIPE_SYSROOT}/${libdir}"`?

Comment: @jmb, I tried that but no luck. I have a workaround which involves creating the links manually in the recipe but it feels like a bodge. Surely there is a way to configure the build so that the libraries are all staged to the same directory before compilation starts.

Comment: @mark next time you can also try the yocto mailing list, but I am not sure it will work for this kind of specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My eventual solution involves manually creating links to the required libraries within the configure step of the recipe. The code below checks if the require library exists in the `{WORKDIR}/usr/lib` directory, if not it creates a symbolic link to the version in the `{WORKDIR}/lib` directory.

```
DEPENDS += " clang ncurses libsdl2"

USR_LIB_WORKDIR = "${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/${libdir}"
BASE_LIB_WORKDIR = "${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/${base_libdir}"
export LIBCLANG_PATH = "${USR_LIB_WORKDIR}"

do_configure:append() {
    if [ -f ${USR_LIB_WORKDIR}/libncurses.so.5 ];
    then
      echo "libncurses.so.5 already exists"
    else
        ln -s ${BASE_LIB_WORKDIR}/libncurses.so.5 ${USR_LIB_WORKDIR}/libncurses.so.5
    fi

    if [ -f ${USR_LIB_WORKDIR}/libtinfo.so.5 ];
    then
      echo "libtinfo.so.5 already exists"
    else
        ln -s ${BASE_LIB_WORKDIR}/libtinfo.so.5 ${USR_LIB_WORKDIR}/libtinfo.so.5
    fi
}
```

I am sure the recipe could be improved by extracting the test & create link operation above into a separate function but at present I am unsure how to create/call functions that take parameters in Yocto recipes.

Comment: Just note that unless you are building for an x86-64 target, the clang library in "${WORKDIR}/recipe-sysroot/${libdir}" has the architecture of the target and I think it is therefore not suitable for bindgen. I used "${TMPDIR}/sysroots-components/x86_64/clang-native/usr/lib/" instead.